# coldfusion string comparison

Tags: string, coldfusion, comparison

I have a form that returns a list like this when submitted:

```
2009,9
```

I want to compare it to database pulled values but keep getting an error.

```
<cfif #FORM.month# eq #qGetDates.year#,#qGetDates.month#>
```

I know I probably have to cast it or convert it to a string for the comparison to work, how do I do this?

Thanks,

R.

Answer (score 13):

```
<cfif FORM.month eq "#qGetDates.year#,#qGetDates.month#">
```

or

```
<cfif compare(FORM.month, "#qGetDates.year#,#qGetDates.month#") EQ 0>
```

Comment: compare() should be the most efficient.  The simple "IS" or "EQ" comparison is case-insensitive, but it has the best readability.  Big performance difference? don't think so.

Comment: `string1.equals(string2)` arguably has good readability but is case sensitive

Comment: Updated comparison of performance can be found here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205694/comparing-100-000-strings. TLDR;  they are about the same in performance, but member functions can be slower

Answer (score 2):

You are overusing #. Unless variables are inside quotation marks or a cfoutput block, you don't  use # as a general rule.

Another rule: You must use quotes around strings (the comma in this case). You can also include variables in your strings with the rule above (use #) as seen in Henry's example.

```
<cfif #FORM.month# eq #qGetDates.year#,#qGetDates.month#>
```

should have # removed and the comma needs the string concatenated

```
<cfif FORM.month eq qGetDates.year & "," & qGetDates.month>
```

Or as Henry said

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the second value (a value after first comma), then

```
<cfset x = "2009,7">
<cfoutput>
    #listGetAt(x,2)#
</cfoutput>
```